# Can you convert a Cartesian distribution function to spherical coordinates?

Tags: plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

I'm studying plasmas using kinetic theory, specifically by using a particle-in-cell code. As one of the outputs, I can output the distribution function $f$ of the plasma as a function of up to 3 of $x,y,z,v_x,v_y,v_z$. This distribution function is clearly in Cartesian coordinates. Is there a way to convert this information to understand the distribution function in spherical coordinates?

For example, if I had $f(x, y, v_x)$, is there an easy way to change this into a function of $f(r, v_x)$?

Comment: You may find the following useful:  https://doi.org/10.1029/2008JA013633

Answer (score 0):

$$\rho = f(x,y,z)$$

By definition in spherical coordinates.

$$z= r\cos(\theta)$$
$$x= r\sin(\theta)cos(\phi)$$
$$y= r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$

Substituting the definitions of  x,y,z in favour of spherical coordinate variables, is by definition changing it into a function in terms of a spherical coordinates system

$$\rho = f(r,\theta,\phi)$$

Comment: Since the functional form of the $f$ at the top of this answer is different from the functional form of the $f$ at the bottom of the answer, it might be more clear to use a different symbols (even though physicists often don't do this). For example, use the symbol $g$ for one of the functions like: $g(r, \theta, \phi) = f(x(r,\theta,\phi), y(r,\theta,\phi), z(r,\theta,\phi))$.